# Printing does not work after publishing to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

I have a PDF in a location. When I am trying to print it in visual studio it works. After publish to IIS it doesn't print.

Here is my code:

```
 bool useDefaultPrinter = (Request["useDefaultPrinter"] == "checked");
                string printerName = Server.UrlDecode(Request["printerName"]);
                //create a temp file name for our PDF report...
                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".pdf";
                Process printjob = new Process();
                //printjob.StartInfo.FileName = @"../../../print/pos/print_without_preview/filename.pdf";//path of your file;  
                //printjob.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
                printjob.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("../../../print/pos/print_without_preview/filename.pdf");//path of your file;  
                //printjob.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
                printjob.StartInfo.Verb = "PrintTo";
                printjob.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + ddl_printer_list.SelectedValue + "\"";
                printjob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                printjob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                PrinterSettings setting = new PrinterSettings();
                setting.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
                printjob.Start();
```

Comment: Use relative paths in Server.MapPath like Server.MapPath("~/Directory...") instead of Server.MapPath('../../')

Comment: @L C sory not working

Comment: Web apps on IIS run in session 0 where the configuration is completely different from your VS. Read more and give up your assumptions.